# [MAKEFILE]: How to copy cpp source files from different source folders into one destination folder and use those cpp files to build using MAKE

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, gnu-make

My Current makefile looks like the following, and it build the targets correctly. But it fails to build the targets in one instance, that is when the length of the path to source files becomes too long. Therefore I want to collect all my source files in different folders into one single source directory and then do the make.

Any leads on how I can modify the following makefile to create a flat source directory and use the files in that directory to build using make

```sh
PROJ_DIR := ../
SRC_DIR += $(PROJ_DIR)project
SRC_FILES += $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*/source/*.cpp)
OBJ_DIR := $(PROJ_DIR)TASK
OBJ_FILES += $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp,$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o,$(SRC_FILES))

CXXFLAGS := --c++14

CC_INCLUDE_PATH += -I$(PROJ_DIR)project/include

.PHONY: all clean dirs

all: $(OBJ_DIR) $(OBJ_FILES) 
    "$(COMPILERBIN)"/cc.exe -rvn crackLib.a $(OBJ_FILES)

clean:
    @rm -rf crackLib.a $(OBJ_DIR) $(FLAT_INC_DIR)  

# Build target for directory creation. Intermediate build files will be placed here.
$(OBJ_DIR):
    mkdir -p $@

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp 
    "$(COMPILERBIN)"/cc.exe $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $< $(CC_INCLUDE_PATH) 

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(TSM_SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    "$(COMPILERBIN)"/cc.exe $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $< $(CC_INCLUDE_PATH) 

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SL_SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    "$(COMPILERBIN)"/cc.exe $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $< $(CC_INCLUDE_PATH) 

-include $(OBJ_FILES:.o=.d)
```

Comment: You say that it fails when the path to a source file is too long. Is the problem that Make commands the compiler to build an object file (`foo.o`) in a directory that does not exist (`../TASK/longpath/source/`)?

Comment: Yes exactly, since ./TASK/longpath/source/ is too long, it seems to the compiler that the file doesn't exist. But in reality the source file does exist.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have the source file `$(SRC_DIR)/longpath/source/foo.cpp`, and we want to build the object file `$(OBJ_DIR)/foo.o`. We might wish for this rule:

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/foo.o: $(SRC_DIR)/longpath/source/foo.cpp
    ... $< -o $@
```

But we don't know the path when we write the makefile, so we must ask Make to figure it out at build time.

There is more than one way to do this. The simplest is to use [the `vpath` directive](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Selective-Search).

If we ken the path ahead of time, we could write this:

```
vpath %.cpp $(SRC_DIR)/longpath/source

$(OBJ_DIR)/foo.o: foo.cpp
    ... $< -o $@
```

Make would use `vpath` to search for the source file, and use its full path as the prerequisite (and therefore `$<`).

The `vpath` directive can take multiple directories, and although we don't know the path beforehand, we know how to compute them:

```
vpath %.cpp $(dir $(SRC_FILES))

$(OBJ_DIR)/foo.o: foo.cpp
    ... $< -o $@
```

And once we confirm that this works, we can switch to a pattern rule:

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    ... $< -o $@
```

and change `OBJ_FILES` accordingly:

```
OBJ_FILES += $(patsubst %.cpp,$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o,$(notdir $(SRC_FILES)))

all: $(OBJ_FILES)
    ... $^
```